# Fast recursive search and replace through huge amount of files via bash/sed/awk - is it possible?

Tags: regex, linux, bash, awk, sed

I'm given a directory with sub directories and about 300000 different kinds of text files in there. All related to some production project, changing its architecture isn't an option.

Some tasks require replacing specific strings everywhere they occur. Using `grep` and `sed` takes about 5 minutes for every such a replace. Using `find` and `sed` takes a lot more time...

However, PhpStorm takes some time to index all the files while opening this directory, but after that searching and replacing in all the files with PhpStorm is blazing fast!

Is it possible to achieve a similar behaviour remaining in terminal emulator? To index somehow all files in a given directory for a fast search&replace after that?

Trying to google around I found some tools like `cscope`, `idutils`, `seascope`, but as far as I could check there are serious limitations like search only without an obvious way to replace, or indexing only source files for functions, keywords, etc...

What I'm looking for is a way to index all the files for fast search&replace with auto updated index. Like in PhpStorm but terminal way and open source.

Thanks!

Comment: what if you can call the sed -i ... operation in parallel (10-50) which will work on different set of files at the same time. You might get the strings replaced faster. i.e. do dir in `find /main/location -maxdepth 0`; do echo my dir is $dir; some_file_replace.sh $dir &; usleep 500; done .. now ... where you can put the following code in some_file_replace.sh as .... for files in `find $1 -type f; do echo this is file $file in $1; sed -i "s/xxx/yyy/g' $file; done

Comment: I think I understand what you say, but I doubt it will improve the performance, hence the whole burden is on IO, not on CPU. At least in my case. Thus if I had SSD that would certainly improve, but I haven't and anyway I'd like to have some open source indexing solution.

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
find <base directory> -type f -exec sed -i \
  -e 's/<pattern1>/<replacement1>/' \
  -e 's/<pattern2>/<replacement2>/' \
  ...
  -e 's/<patternN>/<replacementN>/' \
  {} ';'
```

The key there is to specify all the replacements you want to do at the same time, so that you only need one pass over the file set.  If most files will need at least one replacement, then I can't see how you could do much better than that.

If only a few files need replacements, then you could instead do

```
grep -R --files-with-matches '<pattern1>\|<pattern2>\|...<patternN>' <base directory> \
  | xargs sed -i \
  -e 's/<pattern1>/<replacement1>/' \
  -e 's/<pattern2>/<replacement2>/' \
  ...
  -e 's/<patternN>/<replacementN>/'
```

Again, the key is to do all the replacements in one pass through the file list, but this version uses grep to pre-test each file for whether it needs any replacements.  Pre-testing is faster than processing the whole thing with sed when there are no replacements to be made, but you have to run the file through sed anyway when replacements *do* need to be made.

Anything fancier is likely to take you more time to make than you will end up saving.

Do note that generic tools such as grep and sed probably will not work well for you if you need to be smart about which text to replace, such as avoiding replacements in quoted strings.  If you need something like that then you really should use tools that understand the format of the files.

Comment: I know how to use find, grep and sed. I have no way to foresee all the strings that I should replace. I'm looking for some kind of indexing solution as I described in the question. Some open source alternative to PhpStorm preferably command line tool\s.

Comment: Your question says you are looking to use standard command-line tools.  Full-text indexing is not a feature provided by any of the standard tools, as far as I am aware.  You generally find it only in databases.  If you insist on an index-based solution then you are going to have to build it.

Comment: John Bollinger
Thus in "Linux as IDE vs PhpStorm" Linux lacks very useful feature. Kind of disappointing.